# Matplotlib scatter plot x-axis value is messed up

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, visualization

The following demo code of my is producing a plot with the wrong x-axis value.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.9999390392587174, 1.0000609607412827, 1.0000609607412827]
y = [132, 136, 160, 192, 132, 136, 160, 192]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(len(x)):
    ax.scatter(x[i], y[i])

plt.savefig('demo.png')
```

This is the figure that it produces. In the picture, the x-axis seems to be scaled in some way that does not match the data in the code. Can anyone please explain what I did wrong?
[image]

Comment: Looks like a very clever way of writing the axis labels, it so you can see the points - the values are all "+1" from what's written, as it says on the axis!

Comment: Oh, it makes sense to me now. I did not see the +1 at the corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has scaled them correctly to the range of the x-values.
The odd thing is how it's labelled.
You can control this with

```
matplotlib.pyplot.xticks(ticks, labels, **kwargs)
```

Also see

```
x_formatter = matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(x_formatter)
```

which is the option to turn off the "offset" value (which is +1 in this case).

Comment: Thank you, the first method seems to displays the un-scaled value, which is what I was looking for. 

I will accept your answer once StackOverflow allows me to.

Answer (score 1):

Your x axis values are very close, so matplotlib automatically add an offset to x axis (notice `+1` at the bottom right of the plot).
You can prevent it simply with:

```
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset = False)
```

[image]